# Access sun http in jdk 11

Tags: java, module, jboss, wildfly, java-11

I've a working solution but it's not deployable.

I'm at the moment adding this

```
                <path name="sun/net/www/protocol/http"/>
                <path name="sun/net/www/protocol/https"/>
```

to `wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/sun/jdk/main/modules.xml`

in order to not get this error (we use java 11 where sun is private)

```
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/net/www/protocol/http/Handler
```

I'm using a third library thats using sun and I can't upgrade or use another.

Can I somehow do this by jboss cli or trough docker? Because I can't add this in each environment and in production manually..

Comment: Such classes which are not part of the official API can disappear at any time. So,  a 3rd party library that relies on such classes and “can't upgrade or use another” is not a good combination. However, the specified class still exist in JDK 11 and violating the module access rules should not produce a `NoClassDefFoundError`